# Selecting 10 cities records for each country

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

How would you select 10 cities records for each country ordered by id so that the query would be as fast as possible in Oracle database?

This is my table:

```
ID
CITY_NAME
COUNTRY_NAME
SIZE
```

In result I would like to see (to simplify, I am showing only two cities per country):

```
133 LONDON ENGLAND 10
132 SHIRE ENGLAND 2
44 BERLIN GERMANY 10
43 MUNICH GERMANY
```

Comment: Which 10 cities? What is your criteria for chosing them?

Comment: ID - 10 last inserted cities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this picks cities based on ID column

```
WITH CTE
AS
(SELECT 
ID,
CITY_NAME,
COUNTRY_NAME,
SIZE,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COUNTRY ORDER BY ID ) AS ROWNUM 
FROM TABLE
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE ROWNUM<=10;
```

Performance with window function is linear..

There is one more option using cross apply,which could perform better,if your data is distributed in below fashion...

almost all the countries has more than 20-50 cities  and  you want only top 10,with right indexes ,below query(psuedo) can outperform query which uses window functions..

```
select id,country,size from table1 t1 
cross apply(select top 10 city from table2 t2 where t1.country=t2.country);
```

Comment: In Oracle (and SQL in general) the statement termination character `;` should be at the **end** of the statement, not the beginning

Comment: The asker wants a query that would be as fast as possible. Is this query really the fastests, and if yes, then why do you thin so? Could you explain ?